# ERROR: PleskDBException: Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002).

Tags: php, ubuntu, plesk, ovh

when trying to access my dashboard plesk on ovh , this always happens to me, one reason i dont like to use plesk on ubuntu. i am more comfortable with ubuntu.

ERROR: PleskDBException: Unable to connect to database: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (Error code: 2002). Please check that database server is started and accessible. (Abstract.php:69) ;
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The directory /var/lib/mysql-files is missing. This is mysql package bug discussed here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.5/+bug/1637280

Create the required directory:

sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql-files

sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql-files/

sudo chmod 700 /var/lib/mysql-files/